# What is a pattern in dependent pattern matching?

Tags: dependent-type, pattern-matching

I am trying to understand dependent pattern matching while reading Goguen, McBride, and McKinna (2006)'s paper, but couldn't quite grasp the concept. I know regular pattern matching in functional programming, and I think a pattern refers to the left hand side of definitions by case splits (basically a constructor form).

But in the dependent pattern matching case, I couldn't quite understand the definition of a pattern, as in the following definition from the article.
This is because I do not know how to read the grammar. This is probably obvious to those with the training.

[image]

In particular, I don't understand the juxtaposition of forms such as `x   [x] ==> x`. I understand that the pipe sign `|` means "OR". But I am not sure what the juxtaposition is. Is it function application, or something else?

*Could someone help explain how to read the definition/grammar above in natural language, and then*

*What is a pattern and how is it different from a term (well-typed or ill-typed)?*

Answer (score 5, accepted):

So there's a few things going on here. The picture you show is actually 3 different tables, placed side by side to preserve space. This is a sad effect of page limits for papers.

1. The first column is the syntax for patterns and left-hand-sides of function definitions. This is basically a grammar for patterns, and you're right that the bar means "OR". It says:

- A pattern can be a variable, a constructor applied to 0 or more patterns, or some term specially marked to be "inaccessible" (we'll get to this later).
- A LHS is a function name followed by 0 or more patterns. This is how you define named functions by pattern matching.

  So patterns are *almost* a subset of terms, but with the extra syntax for inaccessible patterns.

2. The second column is an erasure operation, that traverses terms and erases the "inaccessible" notations from terms. You can view the arrow as "is defined to be:" they're defining a (meta)-function by cases on the syntax of patterns. This is how you take a pattern and get a term from it, which is necessary for e.g. substituting into another term.
3. The third column is defining the "accessible variables" for a pattern, which basically traverses the term and collects all the variables that are directly arguments to constructors (i.e. not in an inaccessible pattern).

So what are these "inaccessible patterns"? These are values that we know a given part of a pattern must have in order for the entire pattern to be type correct. So when you're running a program, you don't have to check whether a term matches an inaccessible pattern, you just know that it does by virtue of the other patterns.

Say you're defining `f : (x y z : Nat) -> (x + y = z) -> Vec Bool z`.
To define the body of this function, it's enough to use the single pattern
`f x y .(x + y) refl = ...`. I've used `.(...)` instead of underline here, but the idea is the same. If you have a proof that `x + y = z`, and you pattern match on that proof, there is one constructor, `refl`. But the type of `refl` is `a = a`. So we know from the types that `x + y` is the only possible value that `z` can have.

They're a special feature of dependently typed languages, so you won't see them in OCaml or Haskell. It's relevant because the values of the arguments can show up in the *types* of the goal. So here, when we match on `refl`, the type of the right-hand-side of `f` needs to be `Vec Bool (x + y)`, because we refined the value of `z` by matching on `refl`.

In Agda and Idris these are known as "dot patterns", because of the syntax used for them. See e.g. https://agda.readthedocs.io/en/v2.6.4.1-rc2/language/function-definitions.html#dot-patterns